Can serde_json::to_writer_pretty indent with tabs rather than 2 spaces?
Can serde_json::to_writer_pretty indent with tabs rather than 2 spaces?
    let file = std::fs::File::create(&path).expect("Failed to create json file");
    let mut w = BufWriter::new(file);
    serde_json::to_writer_pretty(&mut w, &data).expect("Failed to write to json file");

How do I tell serde_json::to_writer_pretty to use tabs, or is there some other way?
I have a different tool generating JSON with tabs, so I want to use tabs to diff the files.

You would need to use PrettyFormatter::with_indent and Serializer::with_formatter.
let tabs_pretty = serde_json::ser::PrettyFormatter::with_indent(b"\t");
let mut ser = serde_json::Serializer::with_formatter(&mut w, tabs_pretty);
serde::Serialize::serialize(&data, &mut ser).expect("Failed to write to json file");


So I need a dependency on serde? I currently only have serde_json

Does data.serialize(&mut ser) work?

@Adamarla You already have a dependency on serde, since serde_json depends on it.

No, serialize is not available: method not found in 'BTreeMap<&String, &String>'.  the method is available for 'BTreeMap<&std::string::String, &std::string::String>' here use serde::ser::Serialize;. So again I need to depend on serde explicitly

@Adamarla What's wrong with an explicit dependency on serde, though? It's not like your dependency tree gets any heavier, given that serde_json does (and must!) itself depend on serde.

It's not really an issue. Is there a way to tell Cargo to use the serde version that serde_json uses. Or I have to manually make sure they stay in sync? Or is there a way to use the serde from serde_json without setting it in Cargo.toml?
